# Wrapping table around tabularx reduces row height

Tags: tables, captions

When I'm adding a caption to my table, it consumes the same height but including the caption, so that row heights are reduced.

What I want is the same row heights like before, but with a caption added.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|X}
    % content
    \hline
    Daten-E/A
    & Datenverbindung via USB zum Smart Controller
    \\ \cline{2-2}  & Datenverbindung via Bluetooth zu mobilen Endgeräten
    \\ \hline
    Sensorik
    & Integrierter Vibrationssensor
    \\ \cline{2-2}  & Integrierter Temperatursensor
    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|X}
        % content
        \hline
        Daten-E/A
        & Datenverbindung via USB zum Smart Controller
        \\ \cline{2-2}  & Datenverbindung via Bluetooth zu mobilen Endgeräten
        \\ \hline
        Sensorik
        & Integrierter Vibrationssensor
        \\ \cline{2-2}  & Integrierter Temperatursensor
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Technische Daten}
    \label{technische-daten}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Without table wrapped around tabularx. This are my preferred row heights
[image: without table]

With table and caption. Those are the shrinked rows.
[image: with table]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please, be so kind, to include always a compilable MWE (Minimal Working Example).  It helps us to help you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: What should TeX do with your table? Shrink it vertically to fit the caption? That would be really bad typography.

Comment: I cannot see any difference in the table row height for the cases with and without caption in your example. Which makes sense since the caption does not have anything to do with the table. I probably misunderstood something, can you explain the problem a bit more?

Comment: As far I can see your MWE make exactly what you want when compiled with `pdflatex`.

Comment: the caption has no effect at all on the setting of the `tabularx` as that has already been typeset before the `\caption` is read from the file. What change in the output do you want?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just noticed, that wrapping `tabularx` with `table` causes the rows to shrink. I added screenshots.

Comment: @fl034 No. It does not by default affect the space, I edited your example to have a tabularx in and out of `table` Please fix your example  to be an example of the problem. You can not expect people to debug code that you have not shown. Although in this case I would guess you are using `setspace` or similar which is using double space in the main document and single space in tables, in which case the spacing is by design.

Comment: Whatever is causing that effect is not in your example code. You must reduce your original as far as posible but **while still show that error** (and only that error).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you guys are right. Thanks for your patience as this is my first latex-project and also my first question here :-). I have a tex-template from my university with 400 lines just to setup the document. But I was able to find the packages to see the problem. 
Please try again building the example :-)

Comment: I suspect that the `\usepackage{setspace}` in your original is not after `\begin{document}`. Please always test the posted example, preferably use it to generate any image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As predicted:-) the edited code example uses `setspace`. By design that uses single spacing in figures and tables (which is the usual requirement).

If you want to increase the space inside the table just repeat the `\onehalfspacing` after `\begin{table}`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the fix i looked for! Plus, now I know how to ask good questions :-)